# Derived category of coherent sheaves as modules over dg-category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm trying to learn dg-categories and got stuck with the motivation for considering modules over dg-categories. By definition, for a dg-category $A$ the category of modules over it is
$$Mod{-}A=Fun\left(A^{op}, C(mod{-}k)\right),$$
that is the dg-category of contravariant dg-functors from $A$ to the dg-category of complexes of $k$-modules, and its homotopy category is denoted as $D(A)=H^0(Mod{-}A)$. So what should I take as $A$ to get the derived category $D_b(Coh(X))$ of coherent sheaves on an algebraic variety as $D(A)$?

Comment: A dg-algebra is the same thing as a dg-category with a single object; more precisely, the endomorphisms of this object. (Like a group is a groupoid with a single object.) For such a singleton dg-category, the category of modules is naturally equivalent to the dg-category of dg-modules for the underlying dg-algebra.

Comment: @Ben, yes, but what the category of modules over dg-algebra has to do with the category of complexes of coherent sheaves? If I understand it right, then sheaves of sets on an algebraic variety $X$ are modules not over some algebra but over the category of open subsets of $X$ with inclusions as maps. So what should I take instead of the category of open sets such that sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules are modules over this category, and complexes of such sheaves are modules over some corresponding dg-category?

Comment: My comment did not attempt to answer the main question; consider it a reaction to "... got stuck with the motivation for considering modules over dg-categories".

Comment: @evgeny: What's the status?

Comment: @Hanno, yes, indeed! Thank you!

Comment: @evgeny: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:** Describing the bounded derived category as modules over a dg-category is a non-canonical two-step process. In the first step, you realize the category in question as the homotopy category of some dg-category (*not* of modules over it!), and in the second step, you note that there's no difference between the just obtained dg-category and the so-called perfect modules over it.

In summary, you therefore get a description of ${\mathbf D}^b(\text{Coh}(X))$ as the *perfect modules* over some dg-category.

**Note:** You cannot hope for a description as a description as *all* modules over some dg-category, because this would either be trivial or essentially big, whereas ${\mathbf D}^b(\text{Coh}(X))$ is essentially small.

*First step:* As you probably know, ${\mathbf D}^b(\text{Coh}(X))$ is equivalent to the homotopy category ${\mathbf K}^{+,b,\text{Coh}}(\text{QCoh-Inj}(X))$ of bounded below complexes of injective quasi-coherent sheaves with bounded and coherent cohomology. This in turn can be canonically realized as the homotopy category of the dg-category ${\mathbf C}^{+,b,\text{Coh}}(\text{QCoh-Inj}(X))$ which is defined alike, with homomorphism-complexes as the dg-homs.

*Second step:* The dg-category ${\mathbf C}:={\mathbf C}^{+,b,\text{Coh}}(\text{QCoh-Inj}(X))$ is [pretriangulated](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretriangulated+dg-category) and ${\mathbf D}^b(\text{Coh}(X))$ is idempotent complete, so the Yoneda embedding $\textbf{C}\to \textbf{C}\text{-Mod}$ induces a fully faithful functor $\text{Ho}(\textbf{C})\to\text{Ho}(\textbf{C}\text{-Mod})$ identifying $\text{Ho}(\textbf{C})$ with the full subcategory of [perfect dg-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+dg-modules) over $\textbf{C}$.